# Diferencia entre revocar y cerrar sesión en Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, apigoogle

Tengo una duda existencial. el caso que tengo implementado un ***login*** mediante google a una app.

La API de google contiene dos funciones una llamada  `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut` y otra `Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess` lo que logro entender que la primera cierra sesion pero la segunda sera necesaria? ya que al cerrar sesión debería remover todos los permisos.

Las funciones que he creado :

```
 public void logOut(View view) {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();

        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.signOut(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    goLogInScreen();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    public void revoke(View view) {
        firebaseAuth.signOut();

        Auth.GoogleSignInApi.revokeAccess(googleApiClient).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull Status status) {
                if (status.isSuccess()) {
                    goLogInScreen();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

He utilizado las dos funciones y no veo la diferencia. ambas me dirigen a realizar el login nuevamente seleccionando la cuenta del usuario (cuenta de google).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesaria pero es recomendada. Ambas en realidad implican autenticarse nuevamente por eso notas que tienes que realizar el Login.

Como varios productos Google estas serían definiciones:

> **Cerrar**: implica únicamente el cierre de la sesión.
>
> **Revocar**: Revoca el acceso dado a la aplicación actual. **Es usado cuando
> un usuario desea eliminar su cuenta y en este caso el método
> revokeAccess() elimina la información que su aplicación obtuvo de las
> API de Google.**

- En realidad se recomienda proporcionar al usuario la funcionalidad de poder revocar su cuenta.

---

Te sugiero revisar este nuevo método [revokeRefreshToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens)

> [revokeRefreshToken()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-sessions#revoke_refresh_tokens) Puede revocar el token de actualización
> existente de un usuario cuando un usuario informa un dispositivo
> perdido o robado. Del mismo modo, si descubres una vulnerabilidad
> general o sospechas una fuga a gran escala de tokens activos, puedes
> usar la API listUsers para buscar a todos los usuarios y revocar sus
> tokens para el proyecto especificado.
>
> El restablecimiento de
> contraseña también revoca los tokens existentes de un usuario; sin
> embargo, el backend de Firebase Authentication maneja la revocación
> automáticamente en ese caso. En la revocación, el usuario se cierra la
> sesión y se le solicita volver a autenticarse.

Comment: Interesante. bueno creo que seria correcto remover la información del usuario y luego cerrar sesión. Crees que creando una función con los dos atributos tanto de reboke como de logout sea una buena practica ?

Comment: No se tienen que realizar las dos al mismo tiempo, cerrar sesión es suficiente para que el usuario cierre su sesión, pero un usuario pudiera requerir [borrar toda su información algo similar a lo que vemos en Twitter](https://www.wikihow.com/images/thumb/5/5f/Remove-an-Application-Off-Your-Twitter-Account-Step-5-Version-4.jpg/aid2627445-v4-728px-Remove-an-Application-Off-Your-Twitter-Account-Step-5-Version-4.jpg) para las aplicaciones.